# LED data integrity inconsistency issues using Raspberry Pi

Tags: ws2812b

My Raspberry-Pi controls 480 LED's on a WS2812b- strip. I have cut the strips into the shape of large digits and soldered these strips of 4 or 5 LED's together to create the number '8'. I then decide which LED's to light depending on what number I want to display. There are 15 such digits, using 480 LED's all on the same data line. I'm using a logic level shifter to get 5v for the LED's. I have a resistor in the data line and I am adding 5v into the LED strip at various points. This is being used as a cricket scoreboard. Sometimes, it all works fine. Why, if one LED fails to light correctly, do the following ones flash wildly? In the photo, the LED's should all be green. The red LED is the one erroring and this is immediately before the erroring LED's. Why should this LED error in the first place?
[image: Scoreboard digits]

Comment: A diagram is easier to understand the question

Comment: If it fails in the middle of the string, most likely power/decoupling issue

Comment: A detailed schematic of your design would be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Consider using 3 or 5 *data line*s to limit the scope of any single failure. Consider running prefab strips mounted in parallel for redundancy.

Comment: The data line is daisy-chained between all the LEDs. Each LED processes its own data and then passes the rest of the data to the next LED. It makes sense that if one malfunctions, it passes incorrect data to the next LED.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm, trying to upload a photo...

Comment: Is it failing in the middle (red diode is the first bad one) or is it failing everywhere at once (all of those randomly colored diodes are wrong)? To me it looks like you have corrupt data all along the line. Do you have a picture with all pixels the same color green or blue?

Comment: A common cause of problems is the choice of an inappropriate level shifter for the rise time of the signals. The mention of an unspecified resistor is also ominous. If it's failing at random points and not just one bad pixel, explain your wiring in detail.

Comment: @user1850479  Hopefully you can see the photo now. I built this a couple of years ago having never done any electronics before. I have written code, so I was asked to build it. The scoreboard is controlled from a web page and the Pi inside the scoreboard uses wifi to access a 16 character string every 5 seconds.  The string might look like: "H103145 23229423" the first character relating to the Home or Away team, then the rest of the numbers being the values required for each digit in turn on the scoreboard.  A space means no LED's lit. I simply googled how to light up LED's then built it.

Comment: Sometimes the scoreboard works for a couple of hours then starts to go wild and flash all over the place even without a particular LED going bad, so there could be more than one thing wrong with it. I can't remember what resistance the resistor is.

Comment: I think I used a TXS010BE Logic Level Shifter.

Comment: After seeing the picture: I strongly suspect power supply problems for the LEDs. These use a lot of pulsed power, long wires add inductance, which increases noise on power supply at the LED. Recommend adding capacitor between +5V and GND on each strip, maybe 100µF.

Comment: Thanks @bobflux. I'll do that.

Comment: You said you used a resistor on data line. Where exactly this resistor is and what value it has? Is it at LEDs, level shifter output, level shifter input, or Raspberry Pi output? Is the resistor in series or parallel?

Comment: @Justme the resistor is after the logic level shifter and immediately before the first LED. Honestly, I don't know what size it is and it's not easy access to get to it at the moment. Does size matter???? :-)

Comment: @Ian Blindly adding a random value resistance to any circuit may make it fail, or just cause problems in combination with that level shifter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Level shifter for a WS2811 LED strip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444170/level-shifter-for-a-ws2811-led-strip)

Answer (score 0):

When one LED gets incorrect data or it misses a pulse or sees a double pulse, error happens and propagates through that LED to all subsequent LEDs.

I would have liked to see details about the resistor on data line. Now I see in the comments that you say you used TXS010BE for level shifting.

According to almost every question about similar level shifters, the circuits fail to work properly generally because it is just the wrong level shifter for the application.

My suggestion is to get rid of that level shifter and try another type that is known to work.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea which works and which doesn't. Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Do a search here. I think people have asked that here many times already.

Comment: @Ian The resistor will probably make  things worse, so get rid of it or at least use a very small value if you want to experiment.  But really the solution is to pick a normal unidirectional 3.3->5v level shifter.  There are also many hacks online specific to the ws strips that avoid the need for a level shifter entirely.